# Sound is played only in headphone but not through speakersin ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, sound, headphones

Yesterday i saw around 500plus updates in ubuntu one, i just selected update all. It was showing me aroung 500mb data is needed.I clicked ok. After all the updates complete i am not able to hear any sound through speakers but headphone works.
Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Does Settings->Sound display anything when headphone is not plugged in?

Comment: Check out http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/speaker-test.1.html

Comment: If the earphone is plugged in i could hear the sound, when removed no sound at all during the test.

Comment: when i go to system settings ->sound , in output column it displays analog output built-in audio.  It appears even i remove my headphone.

Comment: When i type "alsamixer" cmd in my terminal, i could see "vThis sound device doesn't have any controls". Will this help you in investigation.

Comment: @user2581225 I could see only Analog output option in sound settings. Even when i insert earphone i could see only that.